# Is it a good idea to combine Wordpress listing page with separate react dashboard?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, web-applications, strapi

after a few years break of web development, I now wanted to get back to this topic for a personal project. Before now, I used to work with php and wordpress, but now I want to get bit more modern. I have checked React and very love how it makes the life easier. So I developed a dashboard in React and now I am looking for the best option to build a landing page containing a store directory for this. To save time, I thought to use wordpress for this part because I am more familiar with it.

To get a better image of the project: There should be a landing page (example.com), where anybody can search for shops by location and add new ones to the directory. When a shop owner signs up for a paid plan, he should get access to a separate admin panel (cp.example.com) to manage details which will be shown on a separate page (cp.example.com/shopname).

I have already created the frontend of the shop-specific dashboard (cp.example.com/shopname) in React and now I want to connect it to a CMS (maybe Strapi + Gatsby?) to give shop owners a possibility to login and manage the displayed content. As I have not much experience with React, Strapi, Gatsby or other frameworks, I thought to separate the shop owner part (cp.example.com + cp.example.com/shopname => Gatsby + React) and the landing page with directory (example.com => wordpress) because the directory part can be solved in less than 2 hours with a wordpress theme like Listify.

Now I am wondering if this is a good combination, or will I get security / performance issues doing so? Is it a good idea to save time for the landing page by using a wordpress theme like Listify or am I running into problems when I combine it with Strapi + Gatsby? Can I access WP database entries from a React script and the other way around can I display database content from Strapi on the landing page? Or am I an idiot and there are much better solutions for this problem?

I am open to learn new languages / frameworks, but not necessarily too many at the same time. As the last time I developed a web app, I only used php + html + js, I am now a bit confused about so many new possibilities.

[Layout as image](https://s20.directupload.net/images/210803/eoihse8v.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As most of the questions regarding backend technologies, "it depends". You mention, that you have experience with WordPress, why don't you use it for the entire project then? You can use most of the features offered from WordPress and integrate them to interact with React. In this case, you can use WordPress as Rest API provider.

[REST API Wordpress HandBook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)
[Wordpress REST API for Begginers](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/wordpress-rest-api)

Furthermore, If you expect to have more than few visitors a day (probably thousands) you should use, something more robust like PHP Laravel, which can be used for the landing page (with blade templates you can use it with HTML only if you want) and make your project as robust as you need (Front-end and Back-end)

[Laravel Webpage](https://laravel.com/)

Comment: Thank you! My intention was to stop using php in future and switch to something more...modern. But yes, seems like your are right, the WP Rest API should be good for this use case. I just wanted to check out some new methods of building a customer control panel, because I found the way wordpress handles custom post types and taxonomies very inefficient when they become bit more complex.
I have only worked with vanilla php in past, yes I know I am so...2005... Can you please tell me in a few words, which advantages I get with Laravel in my case?

Comment: Laravel is a robust Framework, that will make your work as a developer, much easier, it will teach you the best practices in the industry. Work in the MVC pattern to separate the logic and the view. It has out-of-the-box features to make your app scalable and secure. For that matter it can serve as a REST API provider, It can handle much more traffic than WordPress is more secure and scalable. 

If you plan to move to other languages (which is not necessary: Frameworks like Laravel / Synphony / YI has taken PHP to the next level ), using a Framework is the way to go.

Comment: You can do a quick review in: https://github.com/topics/framework, there you can see that Laravel is the one with the most starts (on backend framework). Django Framework (python) is the second. If you want to build a pure JS you can go with Node.JS - Express and Frontend with React.

Comment: Many thanks to you, Alexandro! You have opened me a new world.

Comment: If you think your question is resolved, you can upvote the answer and mark it as resolved (in the tick next to the answer)